# Two very basic questions about dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's consider `diamonds` data. I want to calculate two things :

(1) mean of cut==Ideal

(2) how many diamonds are more expensive than 10000$

**My work so far**

```
library(dplyr)
data(diamonds)<-data(diamonds)
#First problem 
diamonds %>%
group_by(cut) %>%
summarize(Mean = mean(carat, na.rm=TRUE)
  cut        Mean
  <ord>     <dbl>
1 Fair      1.05 
2 Good      0.849
3 Very Good 0.806
4 Premium   0.892
5 Ideal     0.703

#Second problem 
diamonds %>% 
summarize(sum(price> 6)) 
  `sum(price > 6)`
         <int>
 1            53940
```

Could you please tell me two things :

(1) How can I extract from the first one mean for the Ideal feature ? I tried to do it by base R functions but I didn't manage

(2) Could you please check if my value in second problem is valid ? I mean I found it on internet, but I found it very unintuitive that `sum()` function counts your observations. Thanks!

Comment: For first problem, you just need `%>% filter(cut=='Ideal')`. Second problem is ok, but you could also use `filter(price>6) %>% summarise(count=n())`. The sum works because any logical TRUE/FALSE value is equivalent to a 1/0 value, so you can use the sum of all 1s where the expression is TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

first question you can add filter(cut=="Ideal") to the pipe (see Daniels comment),

second; diamonds priced over 10000:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

diamonds %>%group_by(cut) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(carat, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% filter(cut=="Ideal")
       

# diamonds priced over 10000:      

diamonds %>% filter(price > 10000) %>% tally()
## equivalent to:
diamonds %>% filter(price> 10000) %>% summarise(count=n())
## equivalent to:
nrow(diamonds[which(diamonds$price >  10000),])
```